# Discrepancy between Seaborn plotted mean and calculated mean. (Python/Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

Hello there wonderful people of StackOverflow!

I have been getting to grips with Python and was starting to feel pretty confident that I knew what I was doing until this doozy came up:

I am plotting and comparing two subselections of a dataframe where "Type" = "area" and "". Seaborn plots a boxplot of these and marks the mean, but when I calculate the mean using .mean() it gives a different answer. Here's the code:

```
plotdata = df[df['Type'].isin(['A','B'])]
g = sns.violinplot(x="Type", y="value", data=plotdata, inner="quartile")
plt.ylim(ymin=-4, ymax=4) # This is to zoom on the plot to make the 0 line clearer
```

[This is the resulting plot, note how the means are ~-0.1 and ~1.5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYqr4.jpg)

But when I calculate them with:

```
print(df_long[df_long['charttype'].isin(['area'])]['error'].mean())
print(df_long[df_long['charttype'].isin(['angle'])]['error'].mean())
```

It returns:

```
0.014542483333332705
-2.024809368191722
```

So my question is, why don't these numbers match?

Comment: Thanks Scott, first timer here, I found out the answer, but if I ask again I'll be sure to post the data.
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Total misunderstanding of basic statistics was the problem!

Box plots (which are inside the seaborn violin plots) plot the interquartile range and the MEDIAN, whereas I was later calculating the MEAN.

Just needed to sleep on it and hey presto all becomes clear.